# Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Define $\mathfrak T = \{ U: A \subseteq U\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$. Then $\mathfrak T$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Define $\mathfrak T = \{ U: A \subseteq U\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$. Then $\mathfrak T$ is a topology on $X$.

I think this is a true statement and I therefore need to prove it. I know I need to show that all 3 parts of a topology are met.

1. Clearly the empty set and $X$ are in the topology since $A$ is a subset of $X$.
2. I know I need to show that an arbitrary unions are included in the topology.
3. I know I need to show that finite number of intersections are in the topology.

How do I show that the last two conditions of the topology are met? Do I let $x \in X$ and then show $x \in A$ and $U$? If so how do I do that?

Comment: This is a special case of: if $\scr F$ is a [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Filter_on_a_set), then $\scr F\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Consider a collection of an arbitrary number of open sets in this topology. Either this collection only contains the empty set (so there is no union to take), or this collection contains some nonempty $U$ of the topology. Since $U$ contains $A$, then the union over all open sets in this collection also contains $A$ and is therefore in the topology as well.
3. Consider a finite collection of open sets in this topology. If the empty set is one of these open sets, then the intersection is empty and therefore in the topology. Otherwise, every open set in this collection contains $A$, so their finite intersection contains $A$ as well, and is therefore in the topology.

Comment: So i need to do a proof by cases for conditions 2 and 3?

Comment: Note for 3 that at no point is the finiteness of the intersection used in the proof; thus this is in fact an [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Yes, there is a case analysis. You should expect this because you are trying to show that a set $U$ is in a union of two sets; you have to break into cases depending on whether you expect it to be in the first part (the empty set) or the second ($\supseteq A$).